# How can i scroll up in text mode of linux

Tags: linux, terminal, text-mode

is it there any way to scroll up and view the contents of text mode?I was trying to view all the files listed as part of my directory

I can scrollup and view the output of text mode,any way to scroll up and view the output?

Comment: Have you tried the Page Up button?

Comment: What terminal program are you using?

Comment: @fixer1234 i m on kali terminal ,its debian based

Comment: Some terminals are more robust than others.  Konsole has a built-in scroll bar (it may be part of the KDE suite).  Check what terminal programs are available and see if one of the alternatives has a scroll bar.

Comment: From Konsole (Kde) and the console I can scroll up and down with shift pgup and shift pgdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've always done is pipe it with the `less` command. For example `ls | less`. Once you do this you can go backwards a single line by pressing the <kbd>Y</kbd> key, or backwards N lines by pressing <kbd>U</kbd>. And of course you can advance forward a single line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>Space</kbd> to advance multiple lines.

For more info on `less` check out `man less`.

Answer (score 6):

Many terminals, whether the bare console or in a window manager, will let you scroll vertically with <kbd>Shift-PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: Does this work in the boot and shutdown kernel log? (Rather than, presumably, the tty you refer to)

Comment: This worked by default. But it was removed in Kernel 5.8 or newer. https://lore.kernel.org/stable/20200915140701.071583717@linuxfoundation.org/